# Setting Python Path system environment variable in Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, path

I tried to set Python Path system environment variable in Windows 7. 
Via `System and Security > System > Advanced System settings > Environment Variables >` then created "New" variable and value:
`C:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1;C:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\Scripts;`

For some reason this not works, when run 'Python-portable' from Command Prompt, its not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: did you try starting a new console?

Comment: by starting new Windows command prompt.

Comment: yes did you try that?

Comment: running Python-Portable command from Windows command line returns `"Python-Portable is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."`

Comment: What did you name the variable? I'm pretty sure it should be placed in the already existing PATH variable, not a new one. try echo %PATH% in the command line, and see the value of that variable. is the executable named python-portable.exe?

Comment: My mistake: I added PYTHON path to `'User variables'` which is above the `'System variables'` box, not to `System variables`. There is many long path variables inside existing `Path`: should I add my pathes there? Should I use semicolon at the end of my path?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Although the last one don't need semicolon.

Comment: Small note: I downloaded python application and want install it: should I place it into the `C:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\Scripts` folder and run install from there?
Or place app in any folder anywhere in system and just run install?